# Why does it seem Ssl_ca / CA authority is not being set for MariaDB server?

Tags: ssl, mariadb, ca

So I have my MariaDB server version: 10.6.12-MariaDB-0ubuntu0.22.04.1 Ubuntu 22.04.

What I would like to accomplish is that I use one-way TLS. If i understand correctly this means my MariaDB server identifies itself with a certificate issued by a trusted party. The client must of course ID itself with username and passwd, however not with any certificate. I would like this one-way TLS connection flawless, where the server CA-certificate is also positively verified.

The problem I'm running into is that while the connection works and seems to be TLS encrypted, the CA certificate seems to be missing. What I observe is that (1) when I connect using my DBeaver Client from home and I get Ssl_ca status, an empty response is given, (2) when I connect using phpMyAdmin, it says "SSL is used without certificate authority". I just cannot find why this is the case. Can you see what may be going wrong here, or what I am doing wrong here? Please let me know if you need more information.

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_ca'; ##Returns empty
```

(1) I have set the SSL-settings in *"/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf"* to point to a certificate with key and root certificate chain from a trusted certificate provider.

```
[mysqld]
ssl_ca = /etc/mysql/cacert.pem ##Two root certificates that I got from provider
ssl_cert = /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem ##Certificate issued by trusted provider
ssl_key = /etc/mysql/server-key.pem ##Key for the certificate
require-secure-transport = on
```

(2) permissions and ownership are OK,
(3) file paths are OK,
(4) MariaDB starts and restarts correctly,
(5) The root certificates belong to the certificate

```
openssl verify -CAfile /etc/mysql/cacert.pem /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem ##Returns OK
```

(6) the issued certificate is in X509 format,
(7) REQUIRE SSL is enabled for my user that I connect remotely from,

```
openssl x509 -text -noout -in /etc/mysql/server-cert.pem ##Returns description of certificate
```

(8) Remote user connects with: Use SSL: Y, Require SSL: Y, Verify server certificate: Y, Any specific client-side certificates set: N.
(9) Connecting remotely with all this works fine,
(10) Ssl_cipher has value: *TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384*

```
SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';
```

(11) Checked with OpenSSL from client server, it shows my certificate with correct certificate chain.

```
openssl s_client -connect my.server.randomtld:3306 -starttls mysql
```

(12) Firewall is all fine, I'm way past that point.

```
iptables -D INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 111.111.111.111 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -s 222.222.222.222 -j ACCEPT
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 3306 -j DROP
```

Answer (score 0):

Neither `ssl_ca` nor `ssl_cipher` are status variables but readonly global variables. They can't be found and therefore an empty result set will be returned.

- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ssl_ca'` should return `/etc/mysql/cacert.pem` as defined in your configuration file.
- `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'ssl_cipher'` should return an empty string, since you didn't defined a cipher.

To check the cipher in use for the current connection you can use status command (`\s`) in command line client or use a client api function (e.g. mysql_get_ssl_cipher in C)

Comment: Thanks @Georg Richter. The statement "SHOW STATUS LIKE 'Ssl_cipher';" returns a cipher when I connect with TLS, and returns empty when not connected with TLS, as expected. See also: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36776/how-can-i-verify-im-using-ssl-to-connect-to-mysql. I think to be honest there's a confusion in your post between "SHOW STATUS" and "SHOW VARIABLES". Connecting with TLS works, including the TLS handshake. The cipher is OK. The issue is that I cannot connect with a fully verified certificate, given that I'm getting an error "SSL is used without certificate authority".